# Storing and Hashing Passwords flask - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

If I'm creating a password for something that is open source (Python - Flask) and I'm hashing passwords, is it secure to just hash them like I have below? Or should I create a config file on the server that isn't in the git repo that stores a salt?  Is it less safe when people can see exactly how someone is hashing a password?  If someone was able to get their hands onto the database and knew the exact method that was used to hash a password, like the code below, would they be able to reverse it easily? or is there something that I can add to make that difficult?

```
login_details_dict['account_id'] = account.account_id
login_details_dict['account_password'] = sha256_crypt.hash(account_password)

login_details = login_schema.load(login_details_dict)
login_details.save_to_db()
```

Comment: Use the last successful access timestamp along with password to hash and store the timestamp along with the hash. This way even if the db is compromised and hash method is known, the timestamp and hash will keep on changing as per successful user login attempts. So this will require a continuous access to db for any successful attacks like rainbow attacks. This is no way foolproof but makes better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; hashing passwords using only one round of SHA-256 for any web application is not secure!

SHA-256 is a hashing algorithm primarily designed for data integrity verification. This means it was optimized for speed. Being optimized for speed makes it vulnerable to bruteforce and dictionary attacks, which consist of guessing the password many times.

Suppose that your login database was leaked, something that happens even to the largest webapps like banks or large corporations. Your password hashes would be exposed to an adversary. What would they do to get to those juicy passwords? They would constantly guess passwords until they found the right one. Bitcoin mining uses a similar mechanism of "hash guessing" for mining, and there are SHA256 ASICs that can perform terahashes per second. Would you feel comfortable with an attacker being able to guess your password trillions of times per second?

A more secure approach would be to use a modern KDF, like Scrypt or Argon2. Modern KDFs are designed to be memory heavy, which limits hashing to the speed of RAM and makes it very difficult to build efficient ASICs for. Because KDFs are slow, it is best to execute the KDF on the client side, then send the KDF hash to the server, and hash the KDF hash one last time on the server side with a fast algorithm like SHA-256. This would allow you to offload the processing to the clients without a hashes from a leaked database being usable as passwords.

Note: JavaScript key derivation can be slow. If you want client-side key derivation to be faster, you could potentially use WebAssembly to accelerate it. Try not to reduce parameters too much; it will make the algorithm easier to bruteforce.

Furthermore, storing a salt in a Git repo sounds like you're planning to have one salt for the entire web application. This is a bad idea, as it means that an attacker can use one iteration of your hashing function/KDF to guess a single password for all your database entries. It's best to generate a random salt for each password, and store it with the password in the database.

While we're here, you might want to protect against timing attacks as well. When comparing the hashes, using a timeable comparison function like a simple "==" would allow attackers to bruteforce a single character in the hash at a time to log in to the system. Using a constant-time comparison function like `itsdangerous.constant_time_compare()` would protect against this type of attack.

Exposing your source code to the world should not make it insecure if you are using modern security practices. Please mind the best security practices listed above along with others when making your web application.

Comment: Here is a GitHub repo I made a while ago porting an implementation of Scrypt to WebAssembly, though you might want to use Argon2 for newer web applications: https://github.com/id01/scrypt-jane/tree/emcc

Comment: Mate, that was a fantastic answer! A question about the salt, how does the salt make a password more secure if it is kept in the same table as the password?

Comment: The salt prevents an attacker from comparing the same hash between different password entries. If you just use one salt, an attacker would be able to run `hash(password, salt)` for each password and compare the result with every entry in the table. By using a unique salt each time, the attacker must run `hash(password, salt)` separately for each password and each entry on the table. What you're thinking of (a secret string stored in the webapp code to make hashes useless with only a database dump) is called a pepper.

Comment: Also, thanks for the comment; I was worried for you for a moment there. There are many security practices that are easy to miss.